# Can i skip the artifact download in the release definition of vsts ? (not after the release is created)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Can i skip the artifact download in the agent phase of release definition in vsts ? (not after the release is created. I am able to do it after release is created). Trying to find how can i do it in release definition. please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can uncheck Select all artifacts in Artifact download section of agent phase:

[image]

Comment: how this can be achieve in TFS 2018 version, because Artifact download option not available there. I have 3 stages, on every stage agent download all artifacts which increases the the release time